# Banner design, for branding on other sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, banner

So, kind of a generic question here.  Best practices, maybe?  I happen to be using Rails, and I built up a site for a buddy.  http://ecorebox.com/ - see that banner we have there?  It shows how many resources we've helped to save?  That can get broken down for each of our clients too.

So, it's come to my attention, that our clients would like that 'banner' on their site to show how they've helped to impact the environment.  What would be the best way to accomplish that?  I was looking to yelp for inspiration:

process an image, and update the image every few days / weeks?

[image: philsbbw]

build a div, and let them put this in their site where they like?

[image: wolfsforeigncarservice]

an iframe?  is that what it's called?  a snippet (essentially) of .js code that creates the div I just mentioned.

Anyone know how yelp does it?  What are these things actually called, so I can search the internet more effectively?  Dynamic Banners?

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of different techniques you could use to create a banner with that functionality.

A lot depends on how much of it you want to be image-based, and how much of the information will come from your local data.

I would recommend you start with a rails "helper" method that returns simple data based on what you are measuring (e.g. "*" or "***" or "*****" depending on rows in your models).  That should be pretty simple if you just build a rails method that returns this string, put that method in a helper, and call the helper from your view.

Then, when that is working, it should be easy to make it more icon-based.  You could replace the "*" with images of stars, etc.  Using the Rails "raw()" method wrapped around your output and change the "*" to "" tags.

If you combine that with some clever CSS styling, it will end up "looking like" an image, but will really be composed of data from your rails project plus nice styling.

Have fun

Comment: hmmm, that's specific to yelp, sure.  OK, though.  So, if I had those ratings in my system, how would I access them from another website?

Comment: OK.. Once you have it so that you can generate them locally, you would have two more steps:  1) Create it as an image on the fly. 2) Expose it as a RESTful service.  You could handle 1 by creating an SVG image on the fly (then convert it to jpg if necessary).  There are tons of resources under google for #2.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to simply buy the banner. There are tons of websites that offer that. 
However, I would recommend you a website I worked with in the past: http://www.servicecombo.com/professional-banner-design/
They are really professionals and their service is great. The price is not so bad either.

Comment: I don't need an ad, or banner built.  this is more of a question of building a div, or using an image.  thanks though.